# How can you define a segment line from the definition of a barycentre?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

In the French article of a line segment of Wikipedia, it is stated that if [A,B] is a segment, then it can be defined as:

> "A set of barycentres of A with the weight of $1 - t$ and B with the
>   weight of $t$ where $t \in  [0,1]$"

What does the barycentre has to do with segments? I am looking for a way to find this affirmation, not prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're more familiar with the $q = p+\vec {pq}$ form.  In that case, you can rearrange the equation $q(t) = (1-t)A+tB$ to get $q(t) = A+t(B-A)$ where $B-A$ is the vector $\vec{AB}$.  So Wikipedia is just saying that a line segment is all of the points $q$ such that $$q(t) = A + t\vec {AB},\quad t\in[0,1]$$

Clearly when $t=0$, $q$ is just $A$.  When $t=1$, $q$ is $B$.  And as $t$ moves from $0$ to $1$, $q$ moves from $A$ to $B$ -- i.e. along the line segment $\overline{AB}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ and $B$ lie in some vector space.  Then this is literally $$ (1-t)A + tB, $$ which is a weighted sum of $A$ and $B$, i.e., the [barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter) of the two objects having masses $1-t$ and $t$, respectively.  Now vary $t$.